# Cppcheclipse seems to have disappeared

Tags: eclipse, installation, plugins

I used to work with cppcheck for a long time and for use within eclipse I made use of the plugin cppcheclipse.
Now I am setting up a new development PC and thus am trying to find the way to install it. Obviously the old update site dl.bintray.com disappeared and I did not yet find a new way to get it. The same error comes up when I work with the marketplace.
Does anyone by chance know where to get it nowadays?

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Christoph

Comment: See https://github.com/kwin/cppcheclipse/issues/108#issuecomment-892168975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an answer here:
https://github.com/kwin/cppcheclipse/issues/108

and the following [download link here](https://github.com/kwin/cppcheclipse/releases/download/1.1.1/com.googlecode.cppcheclipse.repository-1.1.1.zip).

> So work-around to install the plugin:
>
> ```
> Downloads the zip file provided above by AntonKrug
> In Eclipse, select Help-> Install New Software
> Click "Add..."
> In the "Add Repository" dialog, click the "Archive..." button.
> Select your Zip file and then click "Open"
> Click "Add", Then select the cppcheclipse check box,
> Click "Finish" button to install.
> ```
>
> This will not Auto-Update, but at least you'll be able to install the
> plugin. It doesn't seem like there's much active development on the
> plugin anyway.