# Having the new link or solution to publish the Cppcheck code analyzer plugin with a new repository for the the Eclipse editor of the Omnet++

Tags: eclipse, omnet++

Cppcheck is a static analysis tool for C/C++ code. Cppcheck is designed to be able to analyze your C/C++ code even if it has non-standard syntax (common in embedded projects).

I cannot install cppcheclipse because I obtain this message:
"No repository found at [https://dl.bintray.com/cppcheclipse/p2/updates."](https://dl.bintray.com/cppcheclipse/p2/updates.%22)
How can I solve this problem? Because the BinTray has been shut down.
I would be grateful if you could would be grateful if you could publish an update of the plugin with a new repository.

What about for other C++ code analyzer?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried that solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372245/cppcheclipse-seems-to-have-disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372245/cppcheclipse-seems-to-have-disappeared)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think the plugin is a bit old.